# Dynamically Populating each rows from database using php-Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that is dynamically populated from mysql database.User are expected to select a `staff number`, which automatically goes to the DB and fetches his staff number.I have like 10rows. it works fine for the first row but not the subsequent other others.

Please, take a look at the code and advice where I am missing it.

Thanks

```
<tr>
    <th nowrap="nowrap">S/N</th>
    <th nowrap="nowrap">VNO</th>
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Name</th>
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Staff No</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <?php 
  $c=0; 
  $st =mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_flt WHERE mainloc='".$_SESSION['location']."' AND status='Active'"); 
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($st)){  $c++?> 
  <td><?php echo $c;?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="flt[]" value="<?php echo $r['fltno'];?>" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  <td><select name="opname[]" class="form-control" id="subloc">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <?php  
        $fs = getOperators($_SESSION['location']); 
        while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($fs)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f['name'];?>"><?php echo $f['name'];?></option>
    <?php };?>
    </select></td>
  <td id="staffno"></td>
</tr>
```

Ajax side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subloc").change(function(){
        var sname = $("#subloc option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process-opno.php",
            data:{opname:sname}
        }).done(function(data3){
            $("#staffno").html(data3);  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The above fetches the first rows when subloc id is selected successfully into staffno id. 
But it does not do it for the remaining lines. What can i do so, that it will recognise the second line, third line etc and fetches the corresponding staff number into the staffno id .

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using fetch_array twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

**PHP Part** I have added `classes` for select box and select box ajax result

```
<tr>
<?php 
    $c=0; 
    $st =mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_flt WHERE mainloc='".$_SESSION['location']."' AND status='Active'"); 
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($st)){  
    $c++;
?> 
    <td><?php echo $c;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="flt[]" value="<?php echo $r['fltno'];?>" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td>
        <select name="opname[]" class="form-control js-sel-box" data-id="<?php echo $c;?>">
            <option>Select...</option>
            <?php  
                $fs = getOperators($_SESSION['location']); 
                while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($fs)){
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $f['name'];?>"><?php echo $f['name'];?></option>
            <?php 
                };
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="js-sel-box-ajax-result-<?php echo $c;?>"></td>
<?php 
    }//End While
?>
</tr>
```

**Ajax Part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-sel-box").change(function(){
        var sname = $(this).val();
        var result_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process-opno.php",
            data:{opname:sname}
        }).done(function(data3){
            $(".js-sel-box-ajax-result-"+result_id).html(data3);  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, it works, Instead of changing the $(".js-sel-box-ajax-result-"+result_id).html(data3); I can still use  $(".staffno-"+result_id).html(data3);  It works. Thanks a  million.

Comment: @Dave Welcome :-)

Comment: just asking, is there a way of adding a modal form to this page, so that when a button  details is clicked , it will open a modal form and send the information to that page? I will appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

The same old problem with unique ids, change the id into a class,find all your elements based on the changed select

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td select.form-control").change(function(){
    var sname = $(this).val();
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"process-opno.php",data:{opname:sname}})
    .done(function(data3){
    $(this).parent().next("td").html(data3);  
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is working but affects only the first corresponding row. ie if i select row1 name, it gives the staffno of row1, when i do the same on row2 name, it changes the staff no of row1, instead of dispalying teh result for each rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its better to use class identifier instead of id to identify multiple DOM elements; but in yours it can be workable with minimum changes-

```
// use 
var sname = $(this).val();
//put this line just var sname
var $object =$(this);
// instead of 
var sname = $("#subloc option:selected").val();
// this is because- $('#subloc option:selected').val(); always returns the first 
//dropdownList/optionlist from the DOM array, you can use `this` to track which DOM has been change recently 

 // another change in your code $object is $(this) equivalent but will not work inside ajax so you need to create $object as in code above..
 // put this line 
 $($object).parents('tr').find("#staffno").html(data3);
 //instead of 
 $("#staffno").html(data3);
 // above line will search parent tr and will look for DOM element with id staffno a
```